# Angular 2 with errors in Sublime Text 3

Tags: angular, sublimetext3

I try to start a new project in Angular 2 on Windows based on the following repository: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Everything works fine (`npm install`, `npm start`, ...) except that Sublime Text 3 shows me some errors that are not present when I execute the project.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed.git
$ cd angular2-seed
$ npm install
```

Then I open the project with Sublime Text (with the [*TypeScript* package](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin)) and I face some errors/warnings in the code.

## Error #1

Classes with `@Component` decorators show the following error:

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

(it ignores the line `"experimentalDecorators": true` in *tsconfig.json*)

## Error #2

In *src/client/app/about/about.component.ts* for example, on the line:

```
  moduleId: module.id,
```

Sublime shows this error:

> Cannot find name 'module'.

## The *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

## The *package.json*

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/27db8a19f70470f5110482df1a4debc1100ec347/package.json

Do you why I have this 2 errors? I can develop but it's not very pleasant.

Comment: can you please upload your package.json file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved my issue thanks to this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/470

To summarize:

- Go to the User preferences (Ctrl + Shift + P > *Preferences: Settings*)
- Add the following line: `"typescript_tsdk": "C:/...../npm/node_modules/typescript/lib",` (with the appropriate link)
- Restart Sublime Text
- Test if it works in  *about.component.ts* file by pressing F12 when the cursor is on `module.id`
- Enjoy!

Comment: Where can I find this settings in visual studio 2017?

Comment: Thanks God that made the trick. Under Ubuntu (and I guess most of the Debian based distros) the line should be: `"typescript_tsdk": "/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs"`

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my finding with the exact same problem.

I've got this problem and fixed it using the method listed above. 
But after I've brought my frontend app to the server-side file structure (I use flask as my server-side engine), the problem reappears.
I've solved it using changing tsc path from system-wide into `/frontend/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc` - namely, the local version of the typescript I'd used inside my project.
That solved my problem – by now.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding my typescript file as it was cleverly disguised as "tsc" but mine was located in:

```
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib
```

To find it, I ran the command:

```
where tsc
```